# Index of Moderation Mediation vs Conditional indirect effects at values of the moderator

Tags: confidence-interval, spss, interaction, mediation

I'm analyzing a data set with following variables:

X: Continuous (IV)

Y: Continuous (DV)

M: Continuous (Mediator)

W: Categorical [0, 1] (Moderator)

To run moderated mediation analysis, I'm using Hayes Process macro: Model 8.

Here is the result:

**1-**

[image]

**2-**

[image]

As you can see in the first part, in Condition "0", the CI of indirect effect does not include zero whereas in Condition "1" it does.

However, the CI of moderated mediation index includes zero. Meaning the conditional indirect effect is not significantly different across the two conditions.

How can I make a conclusion here? Can I base my conclusion on the CIs of conditional indirect effects and say that, in condition zero there is evidence for mediation which is not supported in condition 1?

Thanks,

Comment: Hi @Benedict M.J.G. , I thought you could help me with this question.

Comment: Hi  @silburn clarke , I'm asking those who could help me with this question and based on your previous activity, I thought you might do.

Answer (score 0):

I have your answer. The index value is the difference in the slopes for the indirect effect ie .3791-.3320. So your results are not contradictory. The fact that one indirect effect is significant and the other is not is not what matters. The index and its CI is a formal test as to whether the difference in the indirect effects is significant. 
Hope this helps.
Alastair Anderson , Cairnmillar Melbourne

Comment: Welcome to CV. Note that your username, identicon, & a link to your user page 
are automatically added to every post you make, so there is no need to sign 
your posts. In fact, we prefer you don't.